# How to troubleshoot broken Rails logger (not accepting log_tags)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've moved a Rails 3.2.5 app from Heroku to a VPS and while the app was working beautifully on Heroku in terms of the log drain output, unfortunately all log output on the VPS and even running locally lacks timestamps or any other tags I'd like to prepend.

After attempting to create a fresh test app and including the following one of the `config/envrionments` or `config/application.rb` I've found that it prepends the indicated tags:

```
config.log_tags = [:uuid, :remote_ip, lambda { |req| Time.now }]
```

Notwithstanding, I've tried everything I can think of so far from combing through the app gems to grepping everything for any occurrence of "log" within the config and lib folders and subfolders (such as initializers).

I don't know, if somehow the Rails logger may be disabled, how can I find this out?  Or what else could be going on here?  Or what should I look for precisely?... Or should I attempt to force Rails logger and, if so, where & what should I insert Rails logger reset code to find out in an attempt to isolate where during system init the problem is occurring?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, you probably need to use `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging`.

```
  config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new($stdout))
```

Comment: This fixed it for me; plain ol `Logger` doesn't make use of `log_tags`.